# 2 dimensional array array

Tags: visual-studio, console-application

Write a Console Application that adds rows of first 2-dimentional array (so- called array1) with rows of a second array (so-called array2) and assign the result to rows of a third array (so-called array3), all of same dimentions. Upperbound of rows and coloumns is N where N is an integer variable taken from user. Values of first array are given by the equation: array1(i,j) = i*N+j. Values of the second array are given by the equation: array2(x,y) = x*N – y. Finally, the program print the result row by row.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged visual studio I presume c# is an appropriate language:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.Write("Enter the value of N:");
    int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] array1 = new int[N, N];
    int[,] array2 = new int[N, N];
    int[,] array3 = new int[N, N];

    //initializing values of array-1
    for(int i=0; i<array1.GetLength(0); i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<array1.GetLength(1); j++) {
        array1[i,j] = i*N+j;
      }
    }

    //initializing values of array-2
    for(int x=0; x<array2.GetLength(0); x++) {
      for(int y=0; y<array2.GetLength(1); y++) {
        array2[x,y] = x*N-y;
      }
    }

    //initializing values of array-3 and printing results row by row
    Console.WriteLine("array3 looks like this:");
    for(int a=0; a<array3.GetLength(0); a++) {
      for(int b=0; b<array3.GetLength(1); b++) {
        array3[a,b] = array1[a,b] + array2[a,b];
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", array3[a, b]));
      }
      Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/HfGl/0)

**Example usage:**

```
Enter the value of N: 6
array3 looks like this:
0 0 0 0 0 0 
12 12 12 12 12 12 
24 24 24 24 24 24 
36 36 36 36 36 36 
48 48 48 48 48 48 
60 60 60 60 60 60
```